# implement middleware for angular routes in laravel

Tags: angular, routes, middleware

I wanted to protect some of **angular routes** with **laravel**.
In **laravel** I can easily use middleware to protect **routes** and **methods** but since my **angular routes** like "**create a post**" or "**edit a post**" are not in the backend structure, I can't use laravel middleware for those..
What should I do ?
How should I protect them if they are admin, so they can see "create post" page which is in angular routes...

Comment: Why not create your own middleware functions for angular? Also, try always adding versions so we can help you better, for example, what angular version are you using?

Comment: @killstreet I want functionality from php, would it be safe to use angular middleware? I use angular version 5

Comment: Why would it not be save using middleware of Angular? Middleware is middleware. It just depends on how you use it. If you write a good  check in Angular it will have the same result as in Laravel.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use laravel's middleware instead of making middleware in Angular you can always create API routes in Laravel, make a HTTP request, and have that go through a laravel middleware. Depending on that you can send an 200 response or any other response you'd like. This way you can still validate requests over Laravel and read the response in Angular. However I would recommend making Angular based middleware when possible.

I'm no expert on Angular but as far as I know you have interceptors which are just perfect for creating your own validation rules => Middleware.

Next up, in your question you stated

> How should I protect them if they are admin, so they can see "create post" page which is in angular routes...

Middleware does not handle what you see on the page generally. Middleware is for validating http request. Small example in your views to make sure a user cannot see the "create post" page in a view would be

```
@if(Auth::check() & Auth::user()->is_admin)
    <a href="route('admin.post.create')">Create post</a>
@endif
```

This should be enough to make sure only admins can see the create post page. To make sure a user cannot visit the page if they would typ this manually would be in a middleware.

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    if(Auth::check() & Auth::user()->is_admin) return $next($request);
    return abort(401)
}
```

Comment: thank you. I researched a little bit and I found that we should not put url or routes that are being used with Angular in laravel.and in laravel we protects with middleware, so when we don't have angular routes in laravel routes, how should I protect those?